# How to resize custom cells in a TableView?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, tableview, xib

I am learning iOS development and Swift. I am trying to create a simple to-do app, with custom cells in a TableView. I have created the custom cell with a XIB file. In this, the cell looks like this:

[image: What it's supposed to look like]

However, when I run the app on the simulator, it looks like this:

[image: What it actually looks like]

Where am I going wrong and how can I Fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can fix the cell height to a default value by putting something like

```
self.tableView.rowHeight = 44.0
```

In your `viewDidLoad`, where tableView corresponds to the `IBOutlet` that is your `UITableView` in your xib file.

If you would like to do this dynamically e.g. by calculating the size of the cell's contents and then resizing the cell so it fits nice and snug, you should implement

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return 44 // The cell's height
}
```

Be sure to set your `UITableView`'s `delegate` to `self` to use this last method.

[Please see this tutorial for more info.](https://www.ralfebert.de/ios-examples/auto-layout/layout-constraints-for-tableview-cell-height/)